# Can't access server over Wi-Fi

Tags: pi-3, wifi, ssh

When trying to ssh or ping my Raspberry Pi server on my LAN I get a "No route to host":

```
$ ping 192.168.50.249                                                                                    SIGINT(2) ↵  10146  16:43:15
PING 192.168.50.249 (192.168.50.249): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
```

This isn't an issue over ethernet and I can connect successfully.

The netstat command *looks* okay

```
$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.50.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.50.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

Port 22 is listening:

```
$ netstat -lpn | grep :22
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

And it looks like my firewall is appropriately configured:

```
$ sudo iptables-save | grep 22
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

The above commands are generally for ssh but I also can't ping.

I have an ASUS router and checked to see if AP Isolation is off - which it is.

The server itself can ping outside connections over Wi-Fi:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=20.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=26.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=18.8 ms
```

My best guess is the router is blocking connections but I can't find anything on there that would suggest so.

As a last resort, I've also tried reinstalling the OS but I'm getting the same issues.

Interestingly, I can access my server over Wi-Fi if the server itself is connected via ethernet.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

**Edit**

A network scan on the server seems to only detect devices that are connected via ethernet

```
$ arp -a
? (192.168.50.1) at a0:36:bc:14:75:f0 [ether] on wlan0
? (192.168.50.203) at 00:1c:2b:52:a2:0d [ether] on wlan0
? (192.168.50.10) at 70:85:c2:d3:25:ec [ether] on wlan0
```

Comment: could the wifi AP be "isolating" wifi clients?

Comment: I don't think so - I don't have AP Isolation on and according to ASUS "wired connectivity between Router and AP will be seen as same network" My ASUS router is connected to my ISP router via ethernet so technically AP Isolation wouldn't work even if I turned it on I believe.

Comment: oh ... two routers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what the actual issue was but I resorted to backing up router settings, factory resetting it and testing - it worked.

I then restored the settings and it still worked so couldn't pinpoint the problem. Either way, the problem is solved now